# Computer Vision API for javascript not working[Beginner's error]

Tags: javascript, azure-cognitive-services

I am new to Microsoft Cognitive services and this problem seems to have an easy fix but it has spoiled my two days. I have just copied the Computer vision for javascript code and replaced my the subscription key with mine and opened the .html file in my browser it says error.

1. DO I have to add something in the code
2. Also, I have nowt provided any image in this code what's he doing without an image?

The script code is here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSSample</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var params = {
            // Request parameters
            "visualFeatures": "Categories",
            "details": "{string}",
            "language": "en",
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/analyze?" + $.param(params),
            beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
                // Request headers
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","{6e07223403d94848be20af6f126fsssd}");
            },
            type: "POST",
            // Request body
            data: "{body}",
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            alert("success");
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert("error");
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

code and preview of error

[image: code and preview of error]

Comment: add the code directly to the question.. not screenshot.. it will be easier to read

Comment: I have just added that code please review and provide your valuable feedback.

Comment: Try without `{}` here : `xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","6e07223403d94848be20af6f126fsssd");`

Comment: It shows syntax error then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not very obvious, in any code snippet from the Cognitive Service API reference page such as [this](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fa) one that I suspect you were using, you **must** provide a value (or remove) wherever it shows `{something}`.  Here's code with suitable values:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSSample</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myKey = "6e07223‌​403d94848be20af6f126‌​fsssd";
    var myBody = {url:"http://www.gannett-cdn.com/-mm-/2d2a8e29485ced74b7537554043aeae2e0bba202/c=0-104-5177-3029&r=x1683&c=3200x1680/local/-/media/2015/07/18/USATODAY/USATODAY/635728260394906410-AP-GOP-Trump-2016.jpg"}
    $(function() {
        var params = {
            // Request parameters
            "visualFeatures": "Categories",
            "language": "en",
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/analyze?" + $.param(params),
            beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
                // Request headers
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", myKey);
            },
            type: "POST",
            // Request body
            data: JSON.stringify(myBody),
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            alert("success");
            debugger;
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert("error");
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```